# How do I capture live video from my webcam using labview 2011?

Tags: image-processing, video-streaming, webcam, labview, live-video

I was wondering if it would be possible to capture the live video from my integrated webcam using Labview 2011(National Instruments). All I need to do for now is put the camera in the front panel. This is not a USB Webcam. It is a chicony USB 2.0 Camera(does not show up as usb on my pc). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LV2012? Is this beta?

The best way to do this is using IMAQdx drivers+Vision Developement module. AFter installing IMAQdx, USB cams usually already show up in Measurement and Automation Explorer and you can try out Snap/Grab... (Tip: Do install whatever driver is included with the hardware/on a cd.)

Then, in LV, just drop the "IMAQ Acquisition Express" vi into your block diagram and you'll be guided through a very quick and easy setup. 
I'm not much into Express vis, but that one is good.

If you don't have Vision Dev Module, look into ADVision (http://vi-lib.com/). It does the same thing, just with OpenCV, but I don't think that every driver is supported.

Comment: LabVIEW 2012 isn't even in beta, so Josh must work at NI to have internal builds. Or must have made an error.

Comment: No, I am part of the FRC(First Robotics Competition) teams and I have been chosen to be our team's lead programmer this year.

Comment: Also, I did make an error in the version I am using. I am using Labview 2011.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, I have finally got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember only USB cameras that have DirectShow filter are supported by the Vision Acquisition Software, which has the IMAQdx that Birgit P. mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

for usb2 you need imaqdx toolkit in vision acquisition part 
also check NIMax after installation to see if labview could find your camera or not 
labview could find and support all useb2 camera if you instal camera diver correctly